# Конвертация CSV таблицы в SQLite на python

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3, csv

Есть CSV таблица ≈ 1gb

[image: Пример таблицы]
Её надо преобразовать в базу данных SQLite. Попробовал следующим образом:

```
import csv, sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('filename.db')
cur = con.cursor()
# cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE tablename(
#     phone INTEGER NOT NULL,
#     uid INTEGER NOT NULL,
#     mail TEXT,
#     first_name TEXT,
#     last_name TEXT,
#     gender TEXT,
#     date_registered TEXT,
#     birthday TEXT,
# );""")


with open('BD.csv','r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    dr = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",")
    to_db = [(i['phone'], i['uid'], i['email'], i['first_name'], i['last_name'], i['gender'], i['date_registered'], i['birthday']) for i in dr]

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO BD (phone, uid, email, first_name, last_name, gender, date_registered, birthday) VALUES (?, ?, ?);", to_db)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Вывод:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Convert_CSV_SQL.py", line 27, in <module>
    to_db = [(i['phone'], i['uid'], i['email'], i['first_name'], i['last_name'], i['gender'], i['date_registered'], i['birthday']) for i in dr]
  File "d:\Convert_CSV_SQL.py", line 27, in <listcomp>
    to_db = [(i['phone'], i['uid'], i['email'], i['first_name'], i['last_name'], i['gender'], i['date_registered'], i['birthday']) for i in dr]
KeyError: 'uid'
```

Целый день сижу и не получается это сделать.

Comment: Самое логичное действие — сделать `print(i)` и посмотреть, что же там есть на самом деле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прошу прощения проблема была в самом файле.